# Cocoa - Gaining Root Access for NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, root, nsfilemanager

I need to move system files with NSFileManager in my application and I don't seem to have root access. What would be the easiest way to go about gaining this privilege?

I have looked into the BetterAuthorizationSample code provided by Apple, and I don't seem how I could have the NSFileManager run its task once its been given approval by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** To update people still using this answer for reference, `BLAuthentication` makes use of an old, and highly unrecommended function called `AuthorizationExecuteWithPriviledges` that, while working, goes against the modern security paradigm, and is deprecated (and has been for a while). You're still allowed to use it, technically, but if you're developing for Mac OS X Lion, you're more than welcome to use the ServicesManagement framework, that allows you to run code with privileges as a helper tool.

For reference on how to create and launch a privileged helper tool, take a look at one of my questions, [Writing a Privileged Helper Tool with SMJobBless()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134841/writing-a-privileged-helper-tool-with-smjobbless).

---

There's no real easy way to authorize `NSFileManager`, so you should look into using the standard `mv` and `cp` tools run under administrator authentication with the `BLAuthentication` class. Unfortunately, the original author's website is down, but you can easily find copies of the class floating around on Google (I can also upload a copy for you if you wish).

---

With `BLAuthentication`, what you are trying to do goes something like this:

```
#define MOVE @"/bin/mv"
if (![[BLAuthentication sharedInstance] isAuthenticated:MOVE]) {
    [[BLAuthentication sharedInstance] authenticate:MOVE];
}

NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"location1", @"location2", nil];
[[BLAuthentication sharedInstance] executeCommand:MOVE withArgs:arguments];
```

The code above will prompt the user for the administrator's password and authenticate the program for the default time limit of five minutes.

---

**WARNING**
Of course, always be careful with system files! Avoid moving or manipulating them when possible, especially if your program is going to be run on someone else's computer (if anything goes wrong, you're going to be blamed)!

Comment: I really appreciate the post! So would I still be able to use the NSFileManager class or would I have to use the command "mv" from now on? By the way, it would be great if you could upload it for me! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Okay so I was able to find the BLAuthentication class and noticed it was from 2001. Would it still work if its like a decade old? Also can you provide any information as to how I would implement the NSTask part?

Comment: Kevin, to clarify some things: a) For regular files, you can still use `NSFileManager`, but for root access, use `BLAuthentication` as shown above. b) Sorry, my mistake; you don't even need `NSTask` (I forgot to update that part of my answer along with the code, but now it's fixed). Just use `-executeCommand:withArgs:` with the path to the command (@"/bin/cp" or @"/bin/mv") to execute the move/copy operation. c) Yes, although `BLAuthentication` is *old*, it still compiles and runs perfectly fine, even under 10.6 (the security frameworks have barely changed over time).

Comment: Also one more thing, would the app continue in all its other stuff once the popup window asking for their password appears? If so, is there a way to pause it and wait for the person to enter its password before any other code after it is run?

Comment: Kevin, the modal window that prompts the user for authorization runs on the main thread, so yes, it essentially 'pauses' the rest of the program and the UI until the user types in an administrator name and password.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the Security framework to your linked frameworks in order to get `BLAuthentication` to work! Xcode Sidebar->Targets->App Name (Double-Click)->General->Add Linked Library->Select Security.framework->Drag in Sidebar to Linked Frameworks

Comment: Sweet got it working! Thanks! If I were to use the command "rm -f" how would I add the force part?

Comment: Just add @"-f" to the arguments array before the locations of the files you want to delete. `NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-f", /* filepaths */, nil];`

Comment: About the warning and "you're going to be blamed". That's what the AT YOUR OWN RISK in every single license is for, which the user agreed to. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you application needs to use root privileges, use Apple's Authorization Services API.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1