# Copying file to a system folder/package

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm doing an app that changes the Trash-icon in Mac OSX... so far I got:

```
- (IBAction)install:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Installing..");
NSLog(@"Trying to move file..");

NSString* src = @"/Users/myuser/Desktop/dashboard.png";
NSString* target = @"/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock/Contents/Resources/tester123.png";
NSError* error = nil;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:src toPath:target error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
}
```

}

I'm getting the error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
```

I believe it's because that Dock isnt a normal folder, but a package? How do I work around this? Or is there a better way to change the trash-icon?

Comment: sOmmer, how could I do this using apis from core foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your target to this (Dock becomes Dock.app):

```
NSString* target = @"/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/Sample.png";
```

You need administrative rights, otherwise you get this error:

```
 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"
```

This command works perfect in Terminal (conclusion: the path is correct).

```
sudo cp /Users/Anne/Desktop/Sample.png /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/Sample.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct, I am getting the administration error. How do I get these rights?

Comment: Acquiring root access for NSFileManager is a bit difficult. Check BLAuthentication, nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599447/cocoa-gaining-root-access-for-nsfilemanager