# Mac Os Qt Copy files on a repertory without sudo auth

Tags: macos, qt, copy, user-identification

I work on `Mac OS` & `Qt` and I'd like to copy files (with a home-made function) in `/Library/Frameworks` but the copy fail each time. The problem is coming from identification but I don't know how to solve it.

Here's my copy function witch work perfectly when copying to home (for example)

```
void copyFolder(QString sourceFolder, QString destFolder)
{
    QDir sourceDir(sourceFolder);
    if(!sourceDir.exists())
        return;
    QDir destDir(destFolder);
    if(!destDir.exists())
    {
        if(destDir.mkdir(destFolder))
        {
            QStringList files = sourceDir.entryList(QDir::Files);
            for(int i = 0; i< files.count(); i++)
            {
                QString srcName = sourceFolder + "/" + files[i];
                QString destName = destFolder + "/" + files[i];
                QFile::copy(srcName, destName);
            }
            files.clear();
            files = sourceDir.entryList(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
            for(int i = 0; i< files.count(); i++)
            {
                QString srcName = sourceFolder + "/" + files[i];
                QString destName = destFolder + "/" + files[i];
                copyFolder(srcName, destName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "There's a problem while creating : " + destFolder;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does current user have permission to write to this location?

Comment: Yes he has... unfortunately. That's why I not sure where this come from.

Comment: `QDir` lacks error reporting. Try to use `mkdir` function and check its return value and errno.

Comment: Meaculpa, the user hasn't permission. `mkdir` work only on *sudo mode*, do you know how to do it via `Qt` ?

Comment: When you use command line, can you write to this location using sudo? Do you have to enter password?

Comment: Yes I can write if I enter my password

Comment: Do you run your program using sudo?

Comment: No and I'd like not to do. Like ask permission when using it and not sudo everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem you have is with permissions, you can solve this, but not with Qt alone.

Apple's solution, for security, is that when an application is required to access something with elevated privileges (in this case, the Frameworks folder), a second helper application is required that is spawned via launchd and it is that 2nd application that is given the privileges to perform the task.

There is an example of this called SMJobBless, which you can see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html): -

However, you'll notice that it is written in Objective-C. If that's new to you, just be aware that it's only an extension of C, so you should be able to pick up the new parts reasonably easily; enough to modify the SMJobBless example for your needs.

With little documentation available for SMJobBless, there's more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134841/writing-a-privileged-helper-tool-with-smjobbless)

Comment: Do you think I can include `ServiceManagement.framework`in my app? Or I've the obligation to deal with an external app?

Comment: You can add Apple frameworks in your .pro file, but you should use the helper app functionality. Unless you're developing a daemon, your app will only have local user rights, so will still not be able to access the Frameworks directory. The reason the help app works, is that it is launched with root privileges, but signed so that only your app can launch it. It doesn't call any special functions from the Frameworks.

Comment: You confirm what I was thinking : I've a problem in my app deployment system. I'll open another question to solve it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149796/qt-mac-os-application-deployment-missing-framework