# Qt Mac OS Application deployment missing framework

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I use `Qt` and `macdeployqt` to deploy my `C++` app.

It include `OpenGL and Qt Frameworks` in the bundle app but miss some others (ie : `SDL`) and the app doesn't work on others system if the `SDL framework` is absent. Here's my pro file

```
QT      += core
QT  += xml
QT  += opengl
QT      += gui

TARGET = StripTest
CONFIG   += console
TEMPLATE = app


#Main app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    StripWindow.cpp \
    MainWindow.cpp \

HEADERS += StripWindow.h \
    MainWindow.h\

#Graphics
SOURCES += \
    ../../libs/PhGraphic/SDLMain.cpp \

INCLUDEPATH +=  ../../libs \
        /Library/Frameworks/ \

LIBS += -framework SDL -framework SDL_image -framework SDL_ttf
```

Should-I compile frameworks too?

**Edit :** the problem isn't solved if I copy the framework manually on the bundle. It has to be present on `/Library/Frameworks/`

Comment: i guess macdeployqt will not copy other frameworks automatically

Comment: And do you know a way to include them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macdeployqt will only copy and fix up the required Qt Frameworks to your application.

If you run "otool -L" on your application's executable (in the Contents/MacOS folder of the bundle), you'll see where the library frameworks are being referenced from.

Other libraries than those from Qt, listed in the .pro file,  will need you to copy them in to the Frameworks folder of the application bundle and then run the command install_name_tool to update the paths of where the application references them.

I suggest you create a batch script for this, to run as a post-process event when compiling Qt OSX apps.