# Getting privilege to write a file to \Library\ColorSync\Profiles\ in a mac application

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-permissions

From my mac application, I need to write a file to \Library\ColorSync\Profiles. For this, the app needs admin privilege to read write to the folder. Is possible to get the same with in the application? Any help will be appreciated.

I am able to pop up the permission dialog with the following code snippet

```
 NSSavePanel *tvarNSSavePanelObj    = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[tvarNSSavePanelObj setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Library/ColorSync/Profiles"]];

__block NSString *filePathexn  = nil;

[tvarNSSavePanelObj beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger tvarInt) {
    if(tvarInt == NSModalResponseOK){
        NSURL* tvarUrl = [tvarNSSavePanelObj URL];
        NSLog(@"doSaveAs filename = %@",[tvarUrl path]);
        NSString *filePath = [tvarUrl path];
        filePathexn = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"rtf"];
        OSStatus status;
        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]isWritableFileAtPath:filePath]){
            NSLog(@"Not Writable at path");
            AuthorizationRef authRef;
            AuthorizationItem right = {kAuthorizationRightExecute, 0, NULL, 0};
            AuthorizationRights rights = {1, &right};
            status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize, &authRef);
            AuthorizationFlags authFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize;
            status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authRef, &rights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, authFlags, NULL);
        }
       BOOL status1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:filePathexn contents:nil attributes:nil];

    } else if(tvarInt == NSModalResponseCancel) {
        return;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"doSave As tvarInt not equal 1 or zero = %3ld",(long)tvarInt);
        return;
    }
}];
```

I need to know how the file write could be done. Still file is not written to the path. Is any tool name need to be specified? Will it be possible with SMJobless() ? Kindly advise a solution!!

Comment: You are not providing crucial information.

Comment: @ElTomato I have made some edits. Could you please comment now?

Comment: Who is your application intended for?  If you intend to distribute your application through Mac App Store, you won't be allowed to prompt the user for administrative authentication.

Comment: @ElTomato It is not distributed through mac app store. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You have status = AuthorizationCreate...  And you then have status = AuthorizationCopyRights, which doesn't seem right.  I think you are supposed to give rights after confirming that authentication is successful.  Secondly, don't you have to initiate authentication before calling NSSavePanel?

Comment: @ElTomato I am getting success till AutherisationCopyRights still not able to write the file to the specified path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution I am posting here. I went through the app distribution guide. It is mentioned that the Authorization APIS are not recommended for an app that is distributed out side of app store. 
Any way this solution is working for me, it is a little hack, I don't know. I try to run the apple script form the application, which gives full privilege to the folder (chmod 777 path) and after finishing my task set back to previous privilege set.

```
- (void)runapplescript{
NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* returnDescriptor = NULL;
NSAppleScript* scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                               @"do shell script \"chmod 777 /Library/ColorSync/Profiles\" with administrator privileges"];
returnDescriptor = [scriptObject executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];

}
```

Comment: Instead of chmod mv is more preferred. Save the item in some temp location and move it to the /Library/ folder.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest 2 approaches. One approach is fast but deprecated. Second approach is modern but needs a bit of coding and reading documentation:

1. You need to write bash script which will do what you need and execute it with privileges which will be granted using something like this: [STPrivilegedTask](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask)
2. Write privileged helper tool which will be installed once on first access with root privileges and you will be able do any privileged operation [How to write privileged helper tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134841/writing-a-privileged-helper-tool-with-smjobbless)

Comment: Hi, could you advise with some more details? Can I use STPrivillaged Task in my project, Will it work now? If I write a privileged Helper tool can I get root privileges to my application? Any sample you have? Please advise

Comment: It depends of what you need implement. STPrivilegedTask will work for you but your code will have few warnings about of deprecation. Bad side of using STPrivilegedTask - it's each time when you will need some privileged operation you will need request password from user. I think its not user friendly. So my suggestion - if this operation rarely used and you don't have time for research helper tool concept- use STPrivilegedTask. Otherwise  use Privileged helper tool.

Comment: But please note, if you want admin privileges without AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges you only need Privileged helper tool.

Comment: My requirement is to generate a file using fwrite() to the /Library/ColorSync/ folder. For this should I write a tool?

Comment: Not at all. But Privileged Helper tool nice to have in application because it will looks useful  for  users not to input password many times.

Answer (score 2):

If it is saving a ColorSync profile you are after, [`ColorSyncProfileInstall`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/colorsync/1463116-colorsyncprofileinstall?language=objc) will do the heavy lifting for you, like prompting the user for permission & authentication. ️

It is also necessary to include the code-signing [`COLORSYNC_PROFILE_INSTALL_ENTITLEMENT`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/colorsync/colorsync_profile_install_entitlement?language=objc) entitlement:

```xml
<key>com.apple.developer.ColorSync.profile.install</key>
<true/>
```

The documentation for the aforementioned symbol can be found in the *ColorSyncProfile.h* header—partially reproduced here for convenience.

```c
CSEXTERN bool ColorSyncProfileInstall(ColorSyncProfileRef profile, CFStringRef domain, CFStringRef subpath, CFErrorRef* error);
   /*
    * profile   - profile to be installed
    * domain    - either kColorSyncProfileComputerDomain or kColorSyncProfileUserDomain.
    *             kColorSyncProfileComputerDomain is for sharing the profiles (from /Library/ColorSync/Profiles).
    *             kColorSyncProfileUserDomain is for user custom profiles (installed under home directory, i.e. in 
    *             ~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles.
    *             NULL is the same as kColorSyncProfileUserDomain.
    * subpath   - CFString created from the file system representation of the path of the file to contain the installed
    *             profile. The last component of the path is interpreted as a file name if it ends with the extension ".icc".
    *             Otherwise, the subpath is interpreted as the directory path and file name will be created from the 
    *             profile description tag, appended with the ".icc" extension.
    * error     - (optional) pointer to the error which will be returned in case of failure.
    *
    *             bool value true is returned if success or false in case of error.
    */
```