# create plist and copy it to folder MacOS Swift

Tags: swift, macos, plist, nsfilemanager

I have been racking my brain on how to create and write a plist to a certain Folder Directory in MacOS. In my case to the LaunchDaemons folder in /Library. I know how to create the plist but its the writing to the LaunchDaemons folder that I am having issues with. This code below from my understanding is for the sandbox but how do I do it outside of the sandbox?  Cheers

```
 let fileManager = FileManager.default
 let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
 let path = documentDirectory.appending("test.plist")
```

I have added the code with the help I have received and have no errors but it is not writing anything to the folder. Here is the code:

```
 let libraryDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let launchDaemonsFolder = libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("LaunchDaemons/test.plist")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: launchDaemonsFolder.path) {

        print(launchDaemonsFolder)


        let plistDictionary : [String: Any] = [
            "ExitTimeOut": 600,
            "Label": "BOOT.SHUTDOWN.SERVICE",
            "ProgramArguments": ["/test.sh"] as Array,
            "RunAtLoad": false,
            "WorkingDirectory": "/"

        ]

        let dictionaryResult = NSDictionary(dictionary: plistDictionary)
        let fileWritten = dictionaryResult.write(to: launchDaemonsFolder, atomically: true)
        print("is the file created: \(fileWritten)")



    } else {

        print("File Exists")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is outdated, it's highly recommended to use the URL related API anyway.

This code creates an URL pointing to `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

```
let libraryDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let launchDaemonsFolder = libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("LaunchDaemons")
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. Since this changes my code now how does one write to the folder after the plist is created and check if the file exists before writing it? Checking to see if it exists is not that important though.

Comment: If you have `let launchDaemonsFile = launchDaemonsFolder.appendingPathComponent("test.plist")` check `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: launchDaemonsFile.path)`

Comment: I have added my test code above and it does not have any errors but its not writing to the folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have no permission to write into `/Library`. This folder is owned by the `system`. You need a helper app with elevated privileges which is not trivial to create.

Comment: ok I will try and do that. I am assuming you mean like a dialog box asking for the user to put in a password to the system before it tries to write to the folder?

Comment: Yes, I mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134841/writing-a-privileged-helper-tool-with-smjobbless)

Comment: awesome ok will check that out and try to incorporate it in my code. cheers