# how to create a directory in /Library/Application Support

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm getting a permission denied error when I try to create a directory "My App Name" in /Library/Application Support/

```
//@"/Library/Application Support/My App Name/"
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSLocalDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My App Name"];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:NULL error:&error]){
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

I don't need to sandbox my app but I read that sandboxing and adding special entitlements would fix it.

I tried adding the exception to the entitlements file but no luck

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
<array>
    <string>/Library</string>
    <string>/Library/Application Support/</string>
</array>
```

any ideas?

EDIT:
I should also note that I am looking to save a file that is shared by all users. I dont want each user to have a different version of the file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you really need to write into the root directory? Why not the user directory? It seems that this is a common issue as can be seen here  http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/305853-writing-global-preferences-file-into-library-preferences-os-lion.html

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599447/cocoa-gaining-root-access-for-nsfilemanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandbox won't override filesystem permissions - it narrows not widens access! `/Library` is not user-writeable. You should use `~/Library/Application Support` (located via the API **not** by hardcoded path).

Comment: I want all users to share the same file.

Comment: If you need to create a directory in `/Library/Application Support` for your application to use then you need to do privilege elevation. This is what is happening when an app asks for permission to do something, often during its first run to set things up. Reading Apple's [Elevating Privileges Safely](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html) is one place to start. You state you don't need the sandbox so this probably does not apply, but just in case: applications in the App Store *cannot* use privilege elevation.