# Getting a permission denied error when I try to create a folder "efiLinq" in /Library/Application Support/

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am getting a permission denied error when I try to create a folder `efiLinq` inside `/Library/Application Support/` path.

```
//@"/Library/Application Support/efiLinq/"

NSError* error = nil;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/Application Support/efiLinq/efiLinq.plist"])
{
    [FileManager createDirectoryAtPath:@"/Library/Application Support/efiLinq" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:NULL error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}
```

The error says: You don't have permission to save the file "efiLinq" in the folder.
Can you please let me know, how to fix this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982406/how-to-create-a-directory-in-library-application-support

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NSFileManager` instead of using static path,[`URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory%3ainDomain%3aappropriateForURL%3acreate%3aerror%3a)

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSURL *supportURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"efiLinq" isDirectory:YES] create:YES error:&error];
if (supportURL == nil) {
    NSLog(@"coud not create directory: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the above command but still it throws the same permission error.